# Camel MyBatis decimal precision to MSSQL Server

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

Am having a bit of trouble with decimal precision an insert statement in myBatis.
Its a list request that sometimes contains values that have a null in some rows...

Effectively what is happening is when we pass a null value through, the decimal precision in other rows gets rounded to the nearest Integer.  If no nulls are passed, then the data works fine

So our mapper file is something like...

```html
 <insert id="insertSales" parameterType="java.util.List">
 
 insert into [dbo].[landing_sales_data] 
   (
      [cust_code]
      ,[sales_value]
   ) 
      values
  <foreach item="sales" collection="list" open="(" close=")" separator="),(">      
   #{sales.custCode}, 
   #{sales.value,jdbcType=DECIMAL,numericScale=2}
  </foreach>            

  </insert>
```

Which should be producing some SQL like

```html
insert into landing_sales_data
(
      [cust_code]
      ,[sales_value]
)
 values(1,11.11),(2,null)
```

But the end result is that we get 11.00 in the table.

We have specified the jdbcType and the numeric scale in the mapper... and a trace on the SQL server confirms that it is sending 11.11 through to the database.

The problem appears that mybatis is setting the parameter that it creates for the null as with a 0 decimal precision that affects non related rows.

any ideas? i hope we are just missing something.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Observed the same thing.

**Workaround**:
Set the decimal values to something like 0.00 before calling MyBatis.

It's better if we can set where we process the data.
But we can do samething in mapper as well.

Ex:

```
<insert id="insertSales" parameterType="java.util.List">

insert into [dbo].[landing_sales_data] 
  (
  [cust_code]
  ,[sales_value]
  ) 
  values
    <foreach item="sales" collection="list" open="(" close=")" separator="),(">      
        #{sales.custCode}, 
        <if test="sales.value!=null">
        #{sales.value,jdbcType=DECIMAL,numericScale=2}
        </if>
        <if test="sales.value==null">
        0.00,
        </if>
    </foreach>
```